# Laravel multiple where with 3 if statements?

Tags: php, laravel

I hae been recently coding in laravel but I have come across something that I don't really understand that well, how can I run a multiple where clause query with laravel for the below code?

```
@if ($businesses->where('business_owner_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_status', '=', 'accepted')->count() > 0)
                        You own a business...
@elseif ($businesses->where('business_owner_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_status', '=', 'pending')->count() > 0)
                        You have a business, but it is currently pending.

  @else
        <p>You can apply to create your own business by clicking the button below.</p>
        <a href="/business/create"><div class="btn btn-default">Create a business</div></a>
  @endif
```

Error: parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

How do I pass the $businesses?

```
Cache::remember('overview.businesses', 1, function() {
            return Businesses::get();
        });

        return view('frontend.business.overview')->withBusinesses(Cache::get('overview.businesses'));
```

Comment: What's the error here?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: At which line you are getting the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

You better not do those kind of filter/search/calculation on your views, they are supposed to be not intelligent, so I would change it to

```
$businesses = Cache::remember('overview.businesses', 1, function() {
    return Businesses::get();
});

$acceptedCount = $businesses->where('business_owner_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_status', '=', 'accepted')->count();

$pendingCount = $businesses->where('business_owner_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('business_status', '=', 'pending')->count(); 

return view('frontend.business.overview', compact('acceptedCount', 'pendingCount'));
```

Then you just have to do in your view:

```
@if ($acceptedCount > 0)
    You own a business...
@elseif ($pendingCount > 0)
    You have a business, but it is currently pending.

@else
    <p>You can apply to create your own business by clicking the button below.</p>
    <a href="/business/create"><div class="btn btn-default">Create a business</div></a>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked great except that it says $acceptedCount is undefined in the view?

Comment: Please check variable names. I just edited to simplify variables passing to the view.